# LOAD DATA INFILE: can't ignore 1st row while skipping columns?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have an application which basically reads data from a csv file and insert it into a MySQL database.

Initially everything was going fine with this (my sql knowledge is a mess, but I'm trying):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

But recently I had to validate which columns from the file that were going to be inserted into de database, so I tried something like this:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED
BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@col1,@col2,@col3,@ignore,@ignore)
SET col1= @col1, col2= @col2, col3= @col3
```

If I take off the "IGNORE 1 LINES" part, the command works fine, but I don't get why this is messing with everything else. I assume it's some syntax mistake, but I tried everything i could think off and still nothing works. Does anyone have a clue?

EDIT:
If I keep the "IGNORE 1 LINES" I get the "You have an error with your SQL syntax; check the manual yadda yadda yadda to use near 'IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1."

For testing, I'm using a simple file, here's the first 5 lines:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
test;test;test;test;test
test2;test2;test2;test2;test2
test3;test3;test3;test3;test3
test4;test4;test4;test4;test4
```

Comment: What exactly does happen when you use `IGNORE 1 LINES`? Do you get any particular error? Can you post first several lines from your file?

Comment: @peterm I edited the post to provide those informations. As I said, I only get a syntax error, but I can't see anything wrong with the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically your statement is correct and should work as expected.

```
mysql> create table tablename 
    -> (
    ->   col1 varchar(32), 
    ->   col2 varchar(32), 
    ->   col3 varchar(32), 
    ->   col4 varchar(32), 
    ->   col5 varchar(32)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/filename.csv' 
    -> INTO TABLE tablename 
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- I'm on a Mac so I'm using \n instead of \r\n
    ->   IGNORE 1 LINES 
    -> (@col1, @col2, @col3, @ignore, @ignore) 
    -> SET col1 = @col1, col2 = @col2, col3 = @col3
    -> ;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from tablename;
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
| col1  | col2  | col3  | col4 | col5 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
| test  | test  | test  | NULL | NULL |
| test2 | test2 | test2 | NULL | NULL |
| test3 | test3 | test3 | NULL | NULL |
| test4 | test4 | test4 | NULL | NULL |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now since you're getting a syntax error my guess is that the problem is most likely not in the `LOAD DATA` statement itself but rather in C# code that you use to build and execute the query string.

Comment: @CarlosYasuda Did it help in any way? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: sorry I took so long to answer. This didn't solve my problem, however it helped me finding a 'workaround'. There was nothing wrong with my C# code as well, and since I didn't find anything else, I started working with temporary tables to filter the columns I do and do not want to keep. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  As it turned out, between `IGNORE` and `LINES` I somehow had an invisible character instead of just spaces<sup>[1]</sup>.

Erasing the line and writing it again solved the issue.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Aside from nonprinting [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) there are several [Unicode punctuation characters](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2000.html) that are invisible.